# How to show active on the dropdown values clicked using angular8

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

i am using Angular8 application, in which i have navigation bar, i have 3 dropdown values namely Agent, Prospect and Competitor, if i click on Agents it is not getting highlighted, so what even dropdown value i click, it should remain highlighted unless i manually click on other option.

HTML:

```
  <li>
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>
        <span class="d-flex flex-grow-1">Marketing</span>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse list-group show" id="collapseExample">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <span class="d-flex flex-grow-1">Agents</span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <span class="d-flex flex-grow-1">Prospects</span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="d-flex align-items-center list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
          <span class="d-flex flex-grow-1">Competitors</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
```

css:

```
.list-group-item-action:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #294f75;
    border-color: #294f75;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1y9kf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: In the example you didn't add the list-group-item list-group-item-action classes anywhere. If i add them to app.component.css Agents become blue when i click it

Comment: it is been added in the <a> tag and it appears and goes off but wont stay on it

Comment: I see. I've posted a short answer, hope it helps you get on the way

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've misunderstood the `:active` pseudo class.

An element is only "active" when you're clicking it or activating it programatically.
Maybe the `:focus` pseudo class suits your needs better.
If not then you will have to track the selected element in your code and add a class/style based on that instead

[Selected element example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kejg5a?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: I added an example. Since it's a menu i assumed you want to track the selection in your real application to render different content